# How do I count a specfic text value in Sharepoint List column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Im currently trying to count the amount times a specific text string ( "1 JAN" & "2 FEB") occurs in SharPoint List column. Below is my code it only returns the first text srting value it does not count[image: SCREEN PRINT OF OUTPUT]

```
function ResultsAT(xData, status) {
    var Month = []
    var dCounts = [i]
    var i = 0;
    var dNumber = 0;

    var TableRowScBrd = "<table>";
        TableRowScBrd += "<TR><TH style='text-align:            Left'>CLIENT</TH><TH>JAN</TH><TH>FEB</TH><TH>MAR</TH><TH>APR</TH><TH>MAY</TH><TH>JUN</TH><TH>JUL</TH><TH>AUG</TH><TH>SEP</TH><TH>OCT</TH><TH>NOV</TH><TH>DEC</TH><TH>Total</TH></TR>";


    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {

        i = i + 1

        var sReportMonth = $(this).attr("ows_ReportMonth");
        var sServiceManager = $(this).attr("ows_ServiceManager");
        sServiceManager = sServiceManager.substr(sServiceManager.indexOf("#") + 1);
        var dCounts = $(this).attr("ows_ReportMonth");
        var Manager = sReportMonth + sServiceManager;
        var dReasons = $(this).attr("ows_ReportMonth");
        dReasons = dReasons.substr(dReasons.indexOf("#") + 1);


        if (Month[sServiceManager] == undefined) 
             {

            Month[sServiceManager] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

             }

           if (Month[sServiceManager] != undefined)
             {

              }

        if (dReasons == "1 JAN") { Month[sServiceManager][0] = dCounts; }
        if (dReasons == "2 FEB") { Month[sServiceManager][1] = dCounts; }
        if (dReasons == "3 MAR") { Month[sServiceManager][2] = dCounts; }


            dNumber = Month[sServiceManager][0] + Month[sServiceManager][1] + Month[sServiceManager][2]
        //                                                                                              TableRowScBrd += "<TR><td>" + sReportMonth  + "</td><td>" + sServiceManager + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><TR>";

    });


                   var key = "";
                  for (key in Month) {
                                                                                                               TableRowScBrd += "<TR><td style='text-align: Left'>" + key + "</td><td>" + Month[key][0] + "</td><td>" + Month[key][1] + "</td><td>" + Month[key][2] + "</td><TR>";
               }

           TableRowScBrd += "</Table>";
         $("#tasksAT").append(TableRowScBrd);



          }
```

Comment: Could you possibly fix the indenting on that code?  It makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Hello... fixed the code hope that makes it easier... im getting desperate at this stage :(

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I cant run your code now to verify, im pretty sure that it returns an xml structure of rows\row. Therefore row would only find the first row.

Comment: Hi Brian... any suggestions on how to change the return structure, relatively new to jscript ... please help

Comment: You can't change the return structure unless you create your own service, all you can do is traverse it. Are you working with sharepoint 2010? If so you can use the client side object model, which is much more structured.

Comment: do you have any links that would be useful ! im using SP 2007 does this version not have "service" ?

Comment: by creating your own service I meant your own web service. An abstract layer to return the structure of your choice. Then again it sounds like this may be above the scope of your immediate knowledge. 

I'd probably start by evaluating your returning xml from xData.responseXML to see what structure you are actually getting back.

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry about the delay getting back to you ... any links you have on the above suggestions woulg be great... thanks